# Projection Operator spectrum equation derivation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to understand how the following left hand side of this spectrum equation becomes the right hand side, no amount of simple algebra manipulations get me to the right hand side.  Can anyone help?

Even accounting for the fact that for Projection Operators $P = P^2$ or that $\lambda^2 = \lambda$.

$$
(\lambda I - P)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} I + \frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda - 1)}P
$$

This equation is mentioned here on Wikipedia, but no source is mentioned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Spectrum

*I am only interested in the algebraic manipulation that got us from the LHS to the right hand side of the above equation*

This question has an answer that makes some hints about the derivation, but its not clear how they got this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4089303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that an inverse of $\lambda I - P$ may be found (if it exists) among the operators $aI + bP$ (and there are theoretical reasons why you might expect this although you do not need to know them), collecting "like terms" in the expansion of the product
$$
(\lambda I - P)(aI + bP) = \lambda a I + \lambda b P - a P - b P^2 = (\lambda a) I + (\lambda b - a - b) P
$$
and wanting this product to be equal to $I = 1 \cdot I + 0 \cdot P$ shows that $\lambda I - P$ will indeed have an inverse of the form $a I + b P$ as long as the scalars $a,b$ satisfy the scalar equations (1) $\lambda a = 1$ and (2) $\lambda b - a - b = 0$.

The equation (1) forces $a = 1/\lambda$ and solving (2) for $b = a/(\lambda-1)$ and putting in $a = 1/\lambda$ in this expression for $b$ gives the desired formula for $(\lambda I - P)^{-1}$.  And of course the hypotheses needed for these formulas to make sense (that $\lambda \not \in \{0,1\}$) are generally the hypotheses that are also needed for $\lambda I - P$ to be invertible.

More generally, suppose an operator $T$ is known to "be a root of a polynomial," i.e. there is some polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $p(T) = 0$, and that $\lambda$ is a complex number.  Performing "polynomial long division" of $p(x)$ by $x - \lambda$ yields a polynomial $q(x)$ (of degree one smaller than $p$) with $p(x) = (x - \lambda) q(x) + p(\lambda)$ (this is sometimes called the "factor theorem" or "remainder theorem" in algebra class).  Evaluating both sides of this polynomial equation at $T$ one obtains
$$
0 = (T - \lambda I) q(T) + p(\lambda) I,
$$
which implies that $(T - \lambda I) q(T) = -p(\lambda) I$.  If $\lambda$ is not a root of $p$, we can divide both sides of this equation by the nonzero complex number $-p(\lambda)$ and deduce that $T - \lambda I$ is invertible with inverse given by
$$
(T - \lambda I)^{-1} = -p(\lambda)^{-1} q(T).
$$
The projection case is the special case $p(x) = x^2 - x$, where if you carry out the polynomial long division you get $p(x) = (x - \lambda)(x + (\lambda - 1)) + \lambda (\lambda - 1)$ so that $q(T) = T + (\lambda - 1) I$ and $-p(\lambda)^{-1} q(T) = \frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda - 1)} T + \frac{1}{\lambda} I$.

Note that an operator on a finite dimensional complex vector space is *always* the root of *some* complex polynomial (e.g. its characteristic polynomial), so the argument above generally provides a formula for $(T - \lambda I)^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $T$ in such cases.  Operators on infinite dimensional complex vector spaces are not guaranteed to be roots of polynomials, but when they are, the above argument applies equally well in those cases.

Comment: do you have a textbook or reference you could point me to where this is explained?

Comment: Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* has most of the above background material, with its Chapter 4 including enough of the general theory of polynomials and its Chapter 8 introducing e.g. the characteristic polynomial of an operator on a finite dimensional vector space.  I am not sure if it discusses this exact application.