# Bijective and bounded of inverse of bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Based on this question:[Spectrum of a projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089212/spectrum-of-a-projection)

> Let $X$ be a banach space and $P\in B(X)$ a projection.
> Show that $\sigma(P) \subset \{0,1\}$.

I understand the answer that

> If $\lambda$ is neither $0$ nor $1$ then from algebraic calculation (using only the fact that $P^2 = P$) we have
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> (\lambda I - P)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} I - \frac{1}{\lambda(1-\lambda)} P\right ) & = I - \frac{1}{(1-\lambda)} P - P\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} I - \frac{1}{\lambda(1-\lambda)} P\right )\\
> & = I - \frac{1}{(1-\lambda)} P - \frac{1}{\lambda} P + \frac{1}{\lambda(1-\lambda)} P \\
> & = I,
> \end{align*}
> $$
> A similar computation (or just the observation that $I$ and $P$ commute with $I$ and $P$) shows that the same operator is a left inverse of $\lambda I - P$, so that $\lambda I - P$ is invertible for all $\lambda \not \in \{0, 1\}$.

But my question is that our definition of invertible is as follows

> A bounded linear operator $T: E\to F$ between normed spaces $E, F$ is called invertible if $T$ is bijective and $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

I can show that if $T_\lambda:=\lambda I - P$ has left inverse then $T_\lambda$ is injective. Let $S:=\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} I - \frac{1}{\lambda(1-\lambda)} P\right )$. Because for $\forall x, y\in X$, $ST_\lambda(x)=ST_\lambda(y)$ implies that $x=y$.

Also, for any $y\in X$, there exists $x=S(y)$ so that
$$
T_\lambda (S (y))=y
$$
So $T_\lambda$ is surjective. **[Question: does it make sense?]**

Moreover, for $\|x\|\le 1$,
$$
\|Sx\|=\|\frac{1}{\lambda} x - \frac{1}{\lambda(1-\lambda)} Px \|\le |\lambda^{-1}|\|x\|+|\lambda^{-1}(\lambda-1)^{-1}\|Px\|
$$
then it is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume $T_\lambda$ is a linear bijective map. Then by open mapping theorem and the fact that $X$ is a Banach space, $T_\lambda^{-1}$ is continuous, thus it is bounded. Therefore it is enough to give $T_\lambda^{-1}$ explicitly, as shown in the link you attached.

What you wrote in the post is the proof that $T$ is invertible linear map then T is bijective. Here by "invertible" I mean there exists a right inverse and left inverse.